# Screen vs. socat

Tags: gnu-screen, socat

There is already a question: [Screen fails to release pty](https://superuser.com/questions/818166/screen-fails-to-release-pty) and there is no answer (only a workaround has been provided so far).

My case is different and I would like to know the answer to the original question. So, why does `socat` (even recent version 1.7.3.0) ignore the `screen` when the last closes the pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple at the end. We have to use `open('/dev/ptmx')` instead of old `openpty()` mechanism.